# Смена настроек netplan из С++ и С++/Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, netplan, dbus

Не удаётся изменить сетевые настройки netplan из программы, написанной на С++/Qt. Программа состоит из трёх частей:

1. Сервис, запускаемый от рута. Он поднимает web-сервер на базе cpphttplib и на запрос GET выдаёт текущий конфиг, а на POST копирует получаемый конфиг в конфигурационный файл netplan и пытается выполнить netplan apply.
2. Backend-сервер на Qt. Реализует REST l3-протокол на основе слегка допиленного Cj, в том числе забирает конфиг, разбирает его через RapidYaml и предоставляет фронту на редактирование, а после редактирования отправляет через POST первому сервису.
3. Frontend на node. Отображает и позволяет редактировать получаемые с backend данные.

Вторая и третья части работают без проблем. В первой работает всё кроме непосредственно выполнения netplan apply (как с sudo, так и без). При любом способе применения настроек netplan сетевая конфигурация настраиваемого сетевого интерфейса слетает (IP-адрес, шлюз и всё прочее теряется), но новые настройки при этом не применяются. Если же применить настройки вручную, из консоли, они применяются - так что настройки правильные, без ошибок. Как временное решение выполняю через QProcess команду "reboot", и это работает - но хотелось применить настройки без перезагрузки, раз уж операционка это позволяет.

Какие способы пробовал (из них ни один не сработал):

1. Сначала хотел сервис даже без Qt написать - выполнял через стандартные средства работы с pipe:

```
    FILE *pipe = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
```

2. Реализовал через pstreams:

```
    redi::ipstream proc("netplan apply", redi::pstreams::pstdout | redi::pstreams::pstderr);
```

3. Прикрутил Qt, запустил через QProcess. Тут примеры приводить не буду, так как перепробовал множество вариантов: как через start, так и через exec и startDetached. И сам сервис как через sudo запускать пробовал, так и через chown делать принадлежащим руту (на случай, если ограничения по владельцу файла мешали).
4. Поиск на форумах дал совет "управляй через DBUS". Нашёл способ применения настроек, работающий из консоли:

```
    busctl call io.netplan.Netplan /io/netplan/Netplan  io.netplan.Netplan Apply
```

Но из консоли он работает, а при вызове через QProcess - нет. Старые настройки сносит, новые не применяет. При этом даже вывод busctl получить удаётся и он пишет b true, то есть якобы настройки применились - но на деле это не так.

5. Наконец, разобрался с QDbus, реализовал через него:

```
  QDBusInterface iface("io.netplan.Netplan", "/io/netplan/Netplan", "",
                       QDBusConnection::systemBus());
  if (iface.isValid()) {
    QDBusReply<bool> reply = iface.call(QLatin1String("Apply"));
    if (reply.isValid()) {
      std::cout << "Netplan apply result is" << reply.value() << std::endl
                << std::flush;
      return 0;
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Call failed: %s\n", qPrintable(reply.error().name()));
      fprintf(stderr, "Call failed: %s\n", qPrintable(reply.error().message()));
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

Тоже не работает, но хотя бы вывод более-менее информативный:

```
Call failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Call failed: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.1737" (uid=0 pid=340526 comm="/home/bmp/QtBuild/test_dbus/test_dbus " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="Apply" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="io.netplan.Netplan" (uid=0 pid=29955 comm="/lib/netplan/netplan-dbus " label="unconfined")
```

То есть кто-то мне запретил доступ, и я не понимаю, кто.

Для проверки попробовал выполнить команду netplan apply из простейшего скрипта на питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["netplan", "apply"])
```

И всё работает! (Разумеется, скрипт через sudo запускал).

Как дальнейшие действия наметил себе переписать сервис на питоне, благо он крошечный. Но очень хочется понять, кто же запрещает мне посылать сообщения через DBUS и почему ни один из механизмов применения настроек не сработал. Если же и рабочий способ кто-то знает - буду вообще счастлив.

Comment: касательно dbus, там ещё надо политику доступа забабахать для системной шины в директории /etc/dbus-1/system.d/, а то просто так нельзя начать слать туда запросы. [аля вот такие](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170118/dbus-systembus-policies)

Comment: Посмотрел. Но это политика доступа к своей шине - а я свою не создаю, я к уже существующей прикрутиться пытаюсь.

Comment: Значит модифицировать политику для этого сервиса. Что такой-то и такой-то может к ней подключаться и выполнять такие-то методы.